# Is it possible to "fool" getpeername using a VPN server on localhost?

Tags: c++, networking, visual-c++, vpn, openvpn

I have some code that uses getpeername to check if the server it's connecting to is hosted locally (127.0.0.1)

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to fool this by hosting a VPN server on the machine and connecting to the remote server through this?

If not, is there any other way a user might be able to fool this while still connecting to the remote server?

Environment is Windows 10.

Edit to clarify: I have an application running locally and connecting to a remote server, I want to know if it's possible to fool that application into thinking it's connecting to a server that's on the local machine while still actually connecting to the remote server.

Comment: How about running the server inside a VM that is running on your machine?  The code would then see the server running at the VM's IP address rather than on localhost/127.0.0.1.

Comment: You can do this in IPv4 with port forwarding + NAT translator. I'm not sure if that would work in IPv6.

Comment: I want to clarify after Jeremy's comment - I'm not looking to run a server on localhost and have it resolve to something else.

I'm looking to connect to a WAN server, but have the application think it's connecting to a local server.